# Can a 1st party application call an API other than the Graph API?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have noticed that when a first-party application is being onboarded, clicking on the "Call an API" section only shows the Graph API as the only possible option. I'm wondering, if possible, what would be the mechanism to onboard an API that is implemented in a custom-built service instead.

Comment: You may want to ask this question on the *internal* Stack Overflow instead.

Comment: It seems that you are referring to an official sample? Can you share related link?

Comment: If you want you web app to call your web api using AAD authentication, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call your web API with AAD authentication, you can refer to [Scenario: A web app that calls web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview).

Different from calling Microsoft Graph API (it only requires you to register an Azure AD app to represent the client app), remember that you need to register two Azure AD apps, one is for client app (front) and the other is for API app (backend). In the API app, you need to expose API. Then you need to configure the client app. Add the permission (scope) which is exposed by API app to the client app.